# How to make a tkinter button sit below other buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I am currently in the middle of coding a small app which involves a menu written in tkinter (python 3.11)
I have two option buttons, and I want to add an exit button under them.
Currently it looks something like this:

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Window title")
root.config(bg='#FFFFFF')
frame = tk.Frame(
    master=root,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

label = tk.Label(
    master=frame,
    text="Select an option",
    height=1,
    width=40,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
label.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, pady=4)

btn1 = tk.Button(
    master=frame,
    text="Option 1",
    height=1,
    width=20,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
btn1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=4, pady=4)

btn2 = tk.Button(
    master=frame,
    text="Option 2",
    height=1,
    width=20,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
btn2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=4, pady=4)

exit_btn = tk.Button(
    master=frame,
    text="Exit",
    height=1,
    width=5,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
exit_btn.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=4, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

I have tried passing `side=tk.BOTTOM` when packing the button but that doesn't seem to help and the exit button is still in the middle instead of below the others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of packing the widgets matters.  You need to pack `label` and `exit_btn` first, so they occupy the top and bottom sides. Then pack `btn1` and `btn2`.

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Window title")
root.config(bg='#FFFFFF')

frame = tk.Frame(
    master=root,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

label = tk.Label(
    master=frame,
    text="Select an option",
    height=1,
    width=40,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)

btn1 = tk.Button(
    master=frame,
    text="Option 1",
    height=1,
    width=20,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)

btn2 = tk.Button(
    master=frame,
    text="Option 2",
    height=1,
    width=20,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)

exit_btn = tk.Button(
    master=frame,
    text="Exit",
    height=1,
    width=5,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)

label.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, pady=4)
exit_btn.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=4, pady=4)

btn1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=4, pady=4)
btn2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=4, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can create another frame called "bottom" to help organize your buttons:

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Window title")
root.config(bg='#FFFFFF')
frame = tk.Frame(
    master=root,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
frame.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

bottom = tk.Frame(
    master=root,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
bottom.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


label = tk.Label(
    master=frame,
    text="Select an option",
    height=1,
    width=40,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
label.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, pady=4)

btn1 = tk.Button(
    master=frame,
    text="Option 1",
    height=1,
    width=20,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
btn1.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=4, pady=4)

btn2 = tk.Button(
    master=frame,
    text="Option 2",
    height=1,
    width=20,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
btn2.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, padx=4, pady=4)

exit_btn = tk.Button(
    master=bottom,
    text="Exit",
    height=1,
    width=5,
    bg='#FFFFFF'
)
exit_btn.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, padx=4, pady=4)

root.mainloop()
```

[Result is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUjWk.png)